# Multi-Touch Frameworks vs. Windows 7 Native support for Multi-touch?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, wpf-controls, multi-touch

Is it still feasible to use the Current Multi-Touch frameworks .. Breeze, Multi-Touch Vista .. etc. While Native support for multi-touch in Windows 7 + .NET 4.0 and WPF ?

What are the advantages of using the mentioned frameworks over Windows 7 .Net 4.0 Transformation, Scale, Rotate Mechanisms ?

Comment: I often wonder about this myself. I've started using surface control toolkit instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the native multi-touch will be the best in terms of performance as well as reliability going forward. I have been using Surface control for Win7 toolkit lately and it has never let me down. So I would stick with .NET4.0 Win7 native touch.

Comment: After sometime of using the Surface SDK, I can say that you are absolutely right, it had been very flexible in terms of multi-touch behaviour and styling.

Though the current support for Surface Control "ElementMenu" doesn't allow any styling at all.